# How was A.M.A.Z.O. able to get Green Lantern's powers?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

Professor Ivo's nanotechnology-based robot A.M.A.Z.O. was able to get everyone's powers by changing its own underlying material structure. That's fine in most of cases, but Green Lantern's powers aren't based on quantum structure of the ring. It needs to be recharged with a Lantern which is connected with the Will Power bank on Oa.

How on Earth did he get access to the Will Power without recharge? Even Green Lantern's ring can't directly access that. It needs to be recharged.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Amazo's initial appearance, he actually drained the powers of the Justice League members temporarily and was able to access the powers of Green Lantern's ring directly from the source.

- Later it was discovered Amazo's access to the Green Energy continued to exist even though he has never charged it at a power battery.
- The source of his Green Energy (or whether it is actually THE Green Energy at all) has not been determined. Amazo's use of the Green Lantern's ring power seems very similar to GLs powers but he rarely uses the power with the skill and facility that Green Lanterns do.
- Given the vast range of powers capable of being generated by the **[power rings of the Green Lanterns](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Power_Ring)**, it is unlikely Amazo is capable of truly creating such a device and is instead utilizing some other energy as a power source for his ring constructs.